# Changing final screenshot resolution for (Chrome) Lighthouse report

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

I am using lighthouse for creating performance reports for a bunch of our own websites. I also need to take a screenshot to see how the website looks on a desktop computer.

It seems like Lighthouse by default takes a screenshot with mobile resolution.

How can I change that?

I am trying to avoid using other libraries like Puppeteer if possible.

Here's some code that runs lighthouse

```js
import lighthouse from 'lighthouse';
import chromeLauncher from 'chrome-launcher';

const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({ chromeFlags: ['--headless'] });
const options = {
    logLevel: 'info',
    output: 'json',
    onlyCategories: ['performance', 'accessibility', 'best-practices', 'seo'],
    port: chrome.port
};
const runnerResult  = await lighthouse(url, options);
```

Lighthouse returns display captures from the audits for:

- `screenshot-thumbnails` - 120px x 213px
- `final-screenshot` - 280px x 498px

Can I get anything larger than that?

Comment: Are you on about Lighthouse in developer tools or Lighthouse the API / CLI? Also are you looking for higher quality images or just the aspect ratio changing to desktop in the loading timeline thumbnails?

Comment: Thank you @graham-ritchie I use LightHouse CLI. I am using for a different aspect ratio for both "final screenshot" and the "filmstrip/timeline thumbnail", please

Comment: Change the "strategy" to "desktop" (it defaults to mobile) in the options you pass in.

Answer (score 4):

### Intro

You need to make use of the `lighthouse CLI options` listed in the documentation - for example see the [github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) readme and the [node-npm documentation.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse#using-the-node-cli)

There are many options, but the ones that are the most interesting option is:

> `--screenEmulation`
>
> Note: See also `--preset` option, or use `--screenEmulation.disabled`
> to disable.
>
> Otherwise you can set these 4 parameters individually:
>
> ```
> --screenEmulation.mobile
> --screenEmulation.width=360 
> --screenEmulation.height=640 
> --screenEmulation.deviceScaleFactor=2
> ```

Also please have a look at the device emulation / emulatedUserAgents, and specifically play with params like the following:

```
lighthouse <url> --chrome-flags="--window-size=1024,768"    
lighthouse <url> --screenEmulation.desktop--screenEmulation.width=1024 --screenEmulation.height=768 --screenEmulation.deviceScaleFactor=2     
lighthouse <url> --screenEmulation.mobile --screenEmulation.width=1024 --screenEmulation.height=768 --screenEmulation.deviceScaleFactor=2
```

and

```
lighthouse <url> --preset=desktop
```

Have a look also at some additional configs located at: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/tree/master/lighthouse-core/config

### Through Nodejs

In terms of launching through nodejs, I need to find my example that I had, but I did find the example from the documentation of lighthouse. In order to run lighthouse + chrome headless from nodejs use the following:

```
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(url, flags = {}, config = null) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch(flags).then(chrome => {
    flags.port = chrome.port;
    return lighthouse(url, flags, config).then(results =>
      chrome.kill().then(() => results));
  });
}

const flags = {
  chromeFlags: ['--headless']
};

launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('https://github.com', flags).then(results => {
  // Use results!
});
```

**PS: Will update with more information soon**

Sources:

- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse
- [node-npm documentation.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse#using-the-node-cli)
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/config/lr-desktop-config.js

Comment: This is awesome!  Are you aware of any way that this works via the node API?

Comment: Also, for sure awarding rep - just keeping open for the remaining days for visibility - if other answers contribute meaningfully I'll just open another bounty for them too

Answer (score 0):

### Use `full-page-screenshot` audit

Worth to mention that in Lighthouse version 7.5 (don't know how it is in previous versions) full sized screenshot is in audit named `full-page-screenshot`.

Take into account that this is a 'full-page' screenshot so its whole website from top to bottom (not only visible above-the-fold content).

Apart from this, @menelaos answer describes everything about manipulating window size and device emulating you would need to get screenshot of any size.

Comment: Thanks! I could get the full page screenshots via: `const finalScreenshot = results.lhr.audits['full-page-screenshot'].details.screenshot.data.split(';base64,').pop();`